# Writing to a java text file without overriding previous inputs and starting on a new line after ever complete entry

Tags: java, filewriter

The idea behind this is to write to a text file with first name, last and a phone number and save it there. However when restarting the section of the program it will automatically start on a new line. Also facing a problem where for some reason the program keeps looping.

```
    System.out.print("Enter First name: ");
    Scanner FN = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fn = FN.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Last name: ");
    Scanner LN = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ln = LN.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    Scanner Num = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num = LN.nextLine();

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\Second year\\OOP\\Coach1.txt", true);

    try {
      writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
      writer.write(fn + "||");
      writer.write(ln + "||");
      writer.write(num + "||");

      writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }


Output:
FirstName|| Last name || number ||  
rob      || hel       ||0774571829 ||  
katie    || bell      || 09275664291 ||
```

Comment: Do you mean `System.out.println`? if you use `println("Hello)` it will be printed on a new line. If you do this with your first line, you will find the expected behaviour: `System.out.println("Enter First name: ");`

Comment: The idea is to have the first, last and phone num of a single line, each time the program restarts it will start on a new line. I'm not talking about the console either. I mean within the text file itself.

Comment: You should only have 1 Scanner for System.in, not 3, but that's probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: It would help if you post the output you expect and also the output you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

inside try block change the line 
writer.write(num + "||");
to 
writer.write(num + "|| \n");

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a simple addition at the end of last section printed for each entry. Change:

```
writer.write(num + "||");
```

to:

```
writer.write(num + "||\n");
```

`\n` is a new line character, it is used in Strings to indicate that this is a place you want to move to the next line with your String. When next time you try to write to this file, it will start from the new line.

If your intention is to have fixed width of your output Strings (in your example it's fixed, filled with white space characters to make it equal in each column), you need to use `System.out.format()` instead of `System.out.println()`. There are a few options how to use it, take a look at this Java tutorial (**The format Method** section, especially the part about **width**):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

By the way, consider adding `finally{}` section to your `try-catch` block and move `writer.close()` to `finally` instead of keeping it in `try` block. It will provide closing writer even if exception occurs before reaching the end of `try` block.